# How to calculate G statistic for the given scatter-plot in R?

Tags: r

This plot shows actual fractions of true values of response variable and prediction interval. This scatter-plot is called accuracy plot in digital soil mapping. G statistic is applied to check the closeness of the observed and expected fractions.  Ideally, the observed fractions are equal to the expected fractions that =1. But I am not sure which package and how to calculate it.

[image]

`dput(Uncertinty_model)`

Comment: Hi Elton Mammadov, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(data)` or if your data is very large `dput(data[1:20,])`. Replace `data` with the name of your actual data. You can [edit] your question and paste the output. Please surround the output with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [`DescTools::GTest`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19/topics/GTest) function as well as the [R companion section on the G statistic](https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/b_04.html).